# Can the data from two resources be mixed?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, dataset, approximation, overlapping-data

There are several sources of temperature-dependent viscosity data, which goes as following:

|:--------------------------------|
| 273.15  | 320.5 | 330.25 |
|---------------------------------|
| 1.2570   | 0.957 | 0.8855  |

(The above data is just an example. In real data there is about 20 points for each compound)

So, having several such datasets with data measured at different temperatures, which statistical tests can I run to make sure data can be united into a single dataset?

1) Can unpaired t-test be applied to such data?
2) There are equations in form $$viscosity = A + B/(C - T)$$ For each set of data reference source gives coefficients of equations. Can they anyhow be compared?
3) Another possible option I see here is to calculate data at all given temperatures using equations above and then directly calculate RMSE between two datasets.

What (regarding the type of data) will be better and more valid option?

Comment: Please clarify: What are the different "sources", how many are there? How many compounds are there? Are all compounds reported in all sources? What are the labels of the rows and columns in the table? What is your research aim? (Are you interested in testing differences between sources or do you want to summarize )

Comment: There are pairs of compounds measured by different experimentators group, and by "sources" here I mean two different articles by different researchers. And for each compound (i.e. butanol) we have two sets of measurements (approx. 20 points) at different temperatures as in example I posted in a question. I am interested in understanding if the measurements for each compound can be united for further statistical modeling.